# How to assign specific colors to specific cells in a Matplotlib table?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

Following the pylab_examples, I have created a simple 2x5 cells table in matplotlib.

**Code:**

```
# Prepare table
columns = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
rows = ["A", "B"]
cell_text = [["1", "1","1","1","1"], ["2","2","2","2","2"]]
# Add a table at the bottom of the axes
ax[4].axis('tight')
ax[4].axis('off')
the_table = ax[4].table(cellText=cell_text,colLabels=columns,loc='center')
```

Now, I want to color cell A1 with `color = "#56b5fd"` and cell A2 with `color = "#1ac3f5"`. All other cells should remain white. Matplotlib's [table_demo.py](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/table_demo.html) as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623056/matplotlib-using-a-colormap-to-color-table-cell-background) example only show me how to apply a color map with pre-defined colors that depend on the values in the cell.

**How to assign specific colors to specific cells in a Matplotlib-generated table?**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The easiest way to colorize the background of cells in a table is to use the `cellColours` argument. You may supply a list of lists or an array with the same shape as the data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Prepare table
columns = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
rows = ["A", "B"]
cell_text = [["1", "1","1","1","1"], ["2","2","2","2","2"]]
# Add a table at the bottom of the axes
colors = [["#56b5fd","w","w","w","w"],[ "#1ac3f5","w","w","w","w"]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('tight')
ax.axis('off')
the_table = ax.table(cellText=cell_text,cellColours=colors,
                     colLabels=columns,loc='center')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can set the facecolor of a specific cell as

```
the_table[(1, 0)].set_facecolor("#56b5fd")
the_table[(2, 0)].set_facecolor("#1ac3f5")
```

Resulting in the same output as above.

Answer (score 3):

@ImportanceOfBeingErnest provided an excellent answer. However, for earlier versions of Matplotlib, the second approach:

```
the_table[(1, 0)].set_facecolor("#56b5fd")
```

will result in a TypeError: `TypeError: 'Table' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` The TypeError can be overcome by using the following syntax instead:

```
the_table.get_celld()[(1,0)].set_facecolor("#56b5fd")
the_table.get_celld()[(2,0)].set_facecolor("#1ac3f5")
```

[See also this example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20885270/2827397)

(Confirmed on Matplotlib 1.3.1)

[image: Sample plot]